# How to choose my image according to the windows phone theme in xaml

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

In my xaml code I have this:

```
<Button  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="3" Height="72"  Name="btnSend" Click="btnSend_Click">
      <Button.Background>
          <ImageBrush x:Name="imButton" ImageSource="/icons/appbar.feature.email.rest.png" Stretch="None"/>
      </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

For the imageSource I use a default icon from sdk, my problem is when I change de theme in light, the icon doesn't change and stay white. How to change this image when changing theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using transparent for solving this problem.

First, create a style for this button:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="IconButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,3,10,5"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="0" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                            <Grid x:Name="ContentContainer" OpacityMask="{TemplateBinding Content}" Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

after that use it as following:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource IconButton}" >
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/icons/home.png">
</Button>
```

more info try find [here](http://timdams.wordpress.com/2011/06/21/creating-a-wp7-app-supporting-dark-and-light-themes/)

Answer (score 0):

Automatic conversion of button image colors is only done on the AppBar. For all other iamges you'll have to do the test yourself.
Something like this will work:

```
var isLightTheme = (Visibility)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneLightThemeVisibility"] == Visibility.Visible;
```

You can then use that boolean to determine which image to show. Having a standard naming convention for the different version of each image is probably recommended and this will make it easier to work with a converter.

Answer (score -1):

You just need using "white" icon. You can find it in Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Icons\dark

Comment: This only applies to `ApplicationBarButton`s but they are using a regular `Button` and so not in the app bar.